# Adding a new NIC to a Docker container in a specific order

Tags: networking, docker, centos, nic, docker-network

I'm trying to have a `CentOS` container with two network interfaces.
After going through the Docker docs and "googleing" a bit, I found [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1824#issuecomment-169522394) that specifies how to achieve this.

Following it, I created a new network (default type: `bridge`)

```
docker network create my-network
```

Inspecting the new network, I can see that Docker assigned it to the subnetwork `172.18.0.0/16` and the gateway `172.18.0.1/16`.

Then, when creating the container, I specifically attach the new network:

```
docker create -ti --privileged --net=my-network --mac-address 08:00:AA:AA:AA:FF <imageName>
```

Inside the container, I can check with `ifconfig` that indeed the interface is present with that IP and mac address:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:AA:AA:AA:FF  
          inet addr:172.18.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:aaff:feaa:aaff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:258 (258.0 b)  TX bytes:258 (258.0 b)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

The problem comes when I connect the container to the default Docker network (`bridge0` a.k.a `bridge`):

```
docker network connect bridge <my-container>
```

Checking now the interfaces in the container:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:11:00:02  
          inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe11:2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2941 (2.8 KiB)  TX bytes:508 (508.0 b)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:AA:AA:AA:FF  
          inet addr:172.18.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:aaff:feaa:aaff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2941 (2.8 KiB)  TX bytes:508 (508.0 b)
```

The interface for my new network gets moved onto `eth1`, meanwhile the interface for the default networks gets `eth0`.

Also, when checking the configuration file for the interface (`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`), I can see that the MAC address specified there differs from the one I manually set up when running the container (`08:00:AA:AA:AA:FF`):

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
HWADDR="52:54:00:85:11:33"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
MTU="1500"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
UUID="25016937-1ff9-40d7-b4c3-18e08af0f98d"
```

> In `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` there is only the configuration file for `eth0`. The file for `eth1` (the newly added interface) is missing.

Due to the requirements of the work I'm involved, I need that the first interface has to be always disabled and its MAC address has to be specifically set.

Any other network-related work must go through the new attached NIC.

**My question is:**

How can I attach a new NIC to the container so `eth0` will have the desired MAC address.

Doing this at image level is also fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal is to have a running container with two NICs: `eth0` and `eth1`.

`eth0` will have a specific MAC address (let's say, `AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA`) and will be disabled. All networking will be done through `eth1`.

> I will assume that the Docker image has a user with rights to execute `ifdown` and/or `ifconfig`

`eth0` is already present in the image and "talks" to the default Docker networ: `bridge` (created when Docker was installed).

We have to modify the config file for `eth0` in the image (`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcg-eth0`) to modify its MAC address: the field called `HWADDR` in the file.

After this, we have to *commit* the changes to a new image. Let's call it *myImage*.

Now, we have to create a new network for the second interface:

```
docker network create myNetwork
```

> By default it is a `bridge` network (which is enough in my case).

Since the requirement is to have `eth0` with a custom MAC address, we have to create the container without specifying a network; which will connect it to the default bridge network.

```
docker create -ti --mac-address=AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA --privileged --hostname=myHostnane --name=myContainer myImage
```

> It is important to create the container with the *--privileged* switch so we can take down the `eth0` interface.

Now, before starting the container, we connect it to the new network:

```
docker network connect myNetwork myContainer
```

Now the container has two interfaces: the original `eth0` for the `bridge` network and the new `eth1` for `myNetwork` network.

At this point, we can start the container:

```
docker start myContainer
```

and then execute the order to take down `eth0`:

```
docker exec myContainer /bin/bash -c "sudo ifdown eth0"
```

> To take down the interface, we must do this when **running** a container. The reason is that any changes in the networking files [will only persist in its running container](https://docs.docker.com/v1.5/articles/networking/#editing-networking-config-files), so it's not possible to commit the down interface (old, but still relevant).

Comment: I Have the same issue, I don't really understand how all of this answers the original question. This issue is discussed a lot throughout the internet, such as in docker tickets, addressed somehow in compose `PRIORITY` and also here :  https://networkop.co.uk/post/2018-03-03-docker-multinet/